# Material design - EditText bottom line color animation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'd like to implement the bottom line color animation of EditText in an Android application, just like the Material Design Lite's [Text Field](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section). I couldn't find any on my research (all results are about floating labels). Any library or other reference how to make these animations?

---

**EDIT**

Clarifying the question, I want the bottom line animation which expands from the middle to the left and right side of the field (not the floating labels, how to make the bottom line color change, or form validations).

You can see the animation when you focus the Text Field component, and whatever animation you see is the one I'm referring to.

Thanks, Humble Potato II

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can create XML Layout like this way
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_layout_dimen_10"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_black">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/lbl_name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/common_text_size_20" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where do you have the color animation?

Comment: Yeah I thought it would be needing some animation XMLs?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use TextInputLayout. 
use [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168) reference.

Comment: I was expecting the expanding bottom line color animating from the middle to the left and right (like the MDL's [Text Field](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section)).